# PDO query with recursion

Tags: php, recursion, pdo

I am creating a URL and do not want a duplicate, so I search db for url, if it exists, I add a -number to the end, but then I need to search the db again to see if that newly created url with the dash-number also exists, if it does I increment it by one, until there are no results, which is when I will keep the unique url.

I thought to use a recursive function to do this but it is not working and I can't figure out why. I have another function that I call to increase the -number if the URL is found, which works fine so is not included here. Here is the code I have so far...

```
function checkDuplicateCategoryURL($catURL, $userID, $db){
    $queryCatURLDuplicate = $db->prepare('SELECT id, url FROM lessonCats WHERE userID = :userID AND url LIKE :catURL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
    $queryCatURLDuplicate->execute(array(':userID' => $userID, ':catURL' => $catURL));
    $listRow = $queryCatURLDuplicate->fetch();
    if (!$listRow) {
      return $catURL;
    } else {
      $categ = increment_string($listRow['url']);
      $queryCatURLDuplicate = null;
      checkDuplicateCategoryURL($categ, $userID, $db);
    }
  }

  $categoryURL = checkDuplicateCategoryURL($categoryURL, $userID, $db);
```

UPDATE: I just thought of doing this with a while loop and it appears to be working, but I still would like to know if this is the best way to do it. Making repetitive calls to the DB seems like a bad thing, but I can't figure any other way to do it.

```
$listRow = true;
  while($listRow){
    $queryCatURLDuplicate = $db->prepare('SELECT id, url FROM lessonCats WHERE userID = :userID AND url LIKE :catURL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
    $queryCatURLDuplicate->execute(array(':userID' => $userID, ':catURL' => $categoryURL));
    $listRow = $queryCatURLDuplicate->fetch();
    if($listRow){
      $categoryURL = increment_string($listRow['url']);
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you have more than two of each URL with the appended number, you could save space as well as avoid this procedure by thinking about how to conceptually pair the URL with a record of its counts.